# Undefined variable and fatal error in php

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to get user info using a function - user_info..
but I cant seem to access the pdo variable in connect.php..

So I have these errors..

> ***Notice: Undefined variable: pdo in C:\xampp\htdocs\assets\function.php on line 33***
>
> ***Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\assets\function.php on line 33***

**connect.php**

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
try {
//Creating connection for mysql
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=store", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
echo "Connected successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

**function.php**

```
function user_info($user, $field)
{

$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT $field FROM susers WHERE id=:id");
$query->bindParam("id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
while ($row =  $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     $info=$row[$field];
     return $info;
}
}
```

**display.php**

```
    ?php
// Start Session

include('int.php');

// check user login
if(empty($_SESSION['id']))
{
    header("Location: notlogged.php");
}

$user = $_SESSION['id']; // get user details
$name=user_info($user, 'fullname');


echo "$name";

?>
```

**int.php**

```
    <?php
session_start();
include('assets/function.php');
include('db/connect.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the usual problem of scope, $pdo is defined at global scope.  You need to pass this into your method to allow it to use it...

```
function user_info($user, $field)
```

becomes...

```
function user_info($pdo, $user, $field)
```

and called by...

```
$name=user_info($pdo, $user, 'fullname');
```

You COULD use `global $pdo;` but this can cause all sorts of issues and passing the variable in is considered the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your code there is a Problem of scope. learn here [Variable Scoping](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Code inside a function have local scope. Your function `user_info` unable to find the $pdo.  For this you need to pass `$pdo` in function argument.

```
function user_info($user, $field, $pdo)
{

$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT $field FROM susers WHERE id=:id");
$query->bindParam("id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
while ($row =  $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     $info=$row[$field];
     return $info;
}

$name=user_info($user, 'fullname',$pdo);
```

another solution is making `$pdo` as `global`

```
function user_info($user, $field)
{
global $pdo; //make $pdo global by using global keyword
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT $field FROM susers WHERE id=:id");
$query->bindParam("id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
while ($row =  $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     $info=$row[$field];
     return $info;
}
```

> make $pdo global by using global keyword

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, Global Scope is not by default inherited inside function scope like other language. As you have defined `$pdo` in global scope, that will by default will not be available inside function.

To make it available inside function, there are two ways can be done without changing function signature.

### 1. Using `global` keyword (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

```
function user_info($user, $field) {
  // After this declaration, Global $pdo will be scoped inside this function.
  global $pdo;
  $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT $field FROM susers WHERE id=:id");
  ...
```

### 2. Using `$GLOBALS` (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)

```
function user_info($user, $field) {
  // With $GLOBALS, you can use any variable defined in global scope inside your function.
  $query = $GLOBALS['pdo']->prepare("SELECT $field FROM susers WHERE id=:id");
  ...
```

> If you are ready to change your function signature (if not already being used in lot of places), you can always pass the global scope variables as a parameter of your function like `function user_info($pdo, $user, $field)`

Answer (score 0):

Please pass your $pdo variable in user_info function.